# Measure the amount of time an agent has their omni empty. How long is someone waiting for work?

Tags: omnichannel

We currently measure the productivity with the average handle time of a case to the amount of active time (irrelevant to whether there is a que of cases or not) This means that if thw agent does not have cases coming in, they get lower productivity levels, which is not fair. I would like to take the "omni empty" time into account for the productivity. How do I build a report on this in Salesforce?

Formula: Time Omni Empty Duration = Time Omni Became Occupied - Time Omni Started Empty